# Weird snapping when adding loop cuts during retopology

Tags: snapping, retopology

I am new to retopologizing and facing issue with snapping.it seems to be snapping to the mesh according to view and not according to the actual geometry anybody know how to get rid of this or is it even normal to behave this way [image]